# C# Вывести значения элементов массива в другой метод

Tags: c#, массивы, классы, объекты

Знания в C# у меня, пока не очень велики, потому прощу прощения за свой, не совсем умный вопрос. (Надеюсь я верно сформулировал название вопроса)

Есть массив созданный на основе элементов класса. 
Нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, расположенную на форме, значения элементов заданного массива выводились в файл через outputFile.
Однако я не могу понять как мне огласить этот массив, чтобы его элементы можно было выводить.

Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Ниже представлен мой код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int z = 10; //размер массива

    public class ConfigStrings
    {
        public int StringID { get; set; }
        public string StringText { get; set; }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConfigStrings[] array_ConfigStrings = new ConfigStrings[z];

        array_ConfigStrings[0] = new ConfigStrings();
        array_ConfigStrings[0].StringID = 1000;
        array_ConfigStrings[0].StringText = "String 1";

        array_ConfigStrings[1] = new ConfigStrings();
        array_ConfigStrings[1].StringID = 1001;
        array_ConfigStrings[1].StringText = "String 2";

        array_ConfigStrings[2] = new ConfigStrings();
        array_ConfigStrings[2].StringID = 1002;
        array_ConfigStrings[2].StringText = "String 3";

        array_ConfigStrings[3] = new ConfigStrings();
        array_ConfigStrings[3].StringID = 1003;
        array_ConfigStrings[3].StringText = "String 4";

        array_ConfigStrings[4] = new ConfigStrings();
        array_ConfigStrings[4].StringID = 1004;
        array_ConfigStrings[4].StringText = "String 5";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string now = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments );
        string name = "test";

        using ( StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter ( Path.Combine ( mydocpath, "autoconfig_" + now + "_" + name + ".txt" ) ) )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
            {
                outputFile.Write( StringID + " - " );
                outputFile.Write( StringText ); 
                //На выходе должно получится "1000 - String 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объявите свой массив, как и словарь, как поле класса и будет счастье.
Также замечу, что размер массива у Вас равен 10 (int z=10) а объявлено только 5 элементов. Или перепишите цикл на foreach, или на длину массива, или скорректируйте z - иначе словите NullException :)

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int z = 2;
        ConfigStrings[] Array_ConfigStrings;

        public class ConfigStrings
        {
            public int StringID { get; set; }
            public string StringText { get; set; }
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Array_ConfigStrings = new ConfigStrings[z];
            Array_ConfigStrings[0] = new ConfigStrings();
            Array_ConfigStrings[0].StringID = 1000;
            Array_ConfigStrings[0].StringText = "String 1";

            Array_ConfigStrings[1] = new ConfigStrings();
            Array_ConfigStrings[1].StringID = 1001;
            Array_ConfigStrings[1].StringText = "String 2";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string now = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string name = "test";

            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(
                Path.Combine(
                    mydocpath, "autoconfig_" + now + "_" + name + ".txt")
                    )
                )
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
                {
                    outputFile.Write(Array_ConfigStrings[i].StringID + " - ");
                    outputFile.Write(Array_ConfigStrings[i].StringText + "\n");
                    //На выходе должно получится "1000 - String 1"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

По применению этой структуры очень похоже, что вам нужен простой словарь.

Для того чтобы к нему организовать доступ из обработчика события нужно хранить его как поле класса.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, string> configs;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        configs = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            {1000, "String 1"},
            {1001, "String 2"},
            {1002, "String 3"},
            {1003, "String 4"},
            {1004, "String 5"}
        };
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string now = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string name = "test";

        using (StreamWriter outputFile =
            new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(mydocpath, "autoconfig_" + now + "_" + name + ".txt")))
        {
            foreach (var config in configs)
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine($"{config.Key}-{config.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. О словарях я и забыл совсем, да и мои познания связанные с ними еще скуднее, потому я не уверен, что они мне подходят. 

В моей задаче, кол-во строк может быть и 10 и 500, и выгружаться в файл будут не все, а только те, что удовлетворяют тем или иным условиям. Потому, я хотел бы все же использовать массивы если это возможно. Чтобы выгружать их по их индексам. Т.е. это , примерно, выглядит так: 
Если Условие 1, выгрузить Строки с ID 1000,1001,1002. в Противном случае ID - 1003,1004,1005

Comment: @AsmadeyStarkk ну коллекции по любым признакам можно удобно фильтровать с помощью linq

Comment: Я понял. С Linq я пока еще не знаком, однако пойду почитаю о нем. Спасибо за информацию и помощь.